# HTML email: -webkit-text-size-adjust not working with table

Tags: html, ios, css

I am making an email newsletter for iOS devices and wanted to control the font size in order to avoid my layout would be collaspsed by the default font size.

I tried the following but it doesn't work. However, it works when I take out the paragraph tags from the table. Can anyone helps? Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN' 'http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd'>  
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' />
<title>Untitled Document</title>  
<meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
<style type='text/css'>  
    body { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }  
</style>  
</head>  

<body>  
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' border='0' style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;'>  
    <tr>  
        <td>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:13px;'>This paragraph is 13px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:12px;'>This paragraph is 12px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:11px;'>This paragraph is 11px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:10px;'>This paragraph is 10px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9px;'>This paragraph is 9px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:8px;'>This paragraph is 8px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:7px;'>This paragraph is 7px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:6px;'>This paragraph is 6px.</p>  
            <p style='-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; font-family:Arial, sans-serif; font-size:5px;'>This paragraph is 5px.</p>  
            </td>  
        </tr>  
    </table>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

add **p** in selector and remove inline text-size-adjust property in all `<p>` elements.

```
body p { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
```